# Ubuntu - List folder in a partition

Tags: ubuntu

My partion /dev/sda2 is full, howover I would like to get a list of all directory located in that partion to clean it up.

Anyway to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls -d */` should work well enough.

EDIT: Thought you might want the one for all subdirectories as well...

`find * -type d`

Comment: Badly, It show me /var for exemple but it's on /sda7... I really only need any folder on the /sda2 partition

Comment: Add `-xdev` to the find. Use `find * -type d -xdev`.

Comment: If you still didn't get it to work because `*` is not specific to a filesystem, type in `mount`, get the path, and use that in place of the `*`.